# Can I convert a percentage value to a decimal value from 0.0 to 10.0 in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I'm looking to compare a database of movie reviews from IDMb and RT to each other, but to do that I'd like to convert the RT percentage score to a 0.0 to 10.0 score in order to graph them on the same axis properly. Is there a way to do this, by dropping the '%' in the RT column and then moving the decimal place to the left one place? For reference, the table looks like this.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df["Rotten Tomatoes"] = df["Rotten Tomatoes"].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace("%", ""))/10)
```

Comment: This also throws a 'TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable'. Maybe there's something in the order of steps that makes that not work?

Comment: looks your dataset has some issues,check for nan or empty string values in the column

Comment: correct, found some nan values to deal with. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "IMDb":[8.8, 8.7,8.5,8.5,8.8],
    "Rotten Tomatoes":['87%', '87%', '84%', '96%', '97%']
})
df["RT"] = df["Rotten Tomatoes"].apply(lambda x: float(x[:-1])/10)
```

- The `x[:-1]` will strip the last character, the '%'.
- `float()` will convert the string to a floating point number.
- Finally divide by 10 to adjust the scale.

If you want a faster way of doing it the last line can change to:

```
df['Rotten Tomatoes'].str.replace('%','').astype(float).div(10)
```

Thanks @Rajith Thennakoon for idea to use `replace`

Comment: Getting thrown a 'TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable'. Could something be done in the wrong order there?

Comment: I tried with the sample data you provided and it worked as @Rajith Thennakoon mentioned below you likely have missing or corrupted data.